# Translating IEnumerator from seconds into minutes?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ienumerator

I am unsure how to translate this into my script. I have a bird script that hovers over the player. I have everything set in float seconds but I want that my `FadeIn()` function and Ienumerator `GameReset()` use 1 minute instead. This will help because I want players to have some time to shoot down the bird without having the issue of the game automatically resetting in a matter of seconds.The point of my game is that if players take too long the bird will attack them causing a reset window to appear.

```cs
public class OwlEx : MonoBehaviour {


    public float waitTime = 10.0f;
    public float fadeTime = 3.0f;
    public float betweenFadesTime = 2.0f;

    // Flag to determine whether or not the player may respond.
    public bool canRespond = false;

    // Flag to determine if the player has responded within the wait time.
    public bool hasResponded = false;

    public GameObject enemy;

    void Start()
    { StartCoroutine(EnemyFadeIn(fadeTime, betweenFadesTime, waitTime)); }

    void Update() {
        if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)) && (canRespond))
        { hasResponded = true; }
    }

    IEnumerator EnemyFadeIn(float timeToFade, float timeBetweenFades, float timeToWait) {
        Debug.Log("An Enemy Is Fading In");
        // Simulating Fade In Time.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToFade);
        // Fade in
         iTween.FadeTo(enemy, 1, 1);
         Invoke("SetMaterialOpaque", 1f);
        Debug.Log("An Enemy Has Appeared");

        yield return ListenForInput(timeToFade, timeBetweenFades, timeToWait);
    }

    IEnumerator EnemyFadeOut(float timeToFade, float timeBetweenFades, float timeToWait) {
        Debug.Log("An Enemy Is Fading Away");
        // Simulating Fade Out Time.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToFade);
        // Fade out
         SetMaterialTransparent();
         iTween.FadeTo(enemy, 0, 1);
        Debug.Log("An Enemy Has Departed");
        // Simulating Time Between Fades.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenFades);

        yield return EnemyFadeIn(timeToFade, timeBetweenFades, timeToWait);
    }

    // Responsible for reacting to the 'S' key input.
    IEnumerator ListenForInput(float timeToFade, float timeBetweenFades, float timeToWait) {
        canRespond = true;
        Debug.Log("Press the 'S' Key to Destroy the Enemy!");
        float startTime = Time.time;

        // Check every 0.25 seconds to see if the S key was pressed.
        while (Time.time < (startTime + timeToWait)) {
            if (hasResponded) {
                Debug.Log("The 'S' Key was Pressed!");
                hasResponded = false;
                canRespond = false;
                yield return EnemyFadeOut(timeToFade, timeBetweenFades, timeToWait);
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.25f);
        }

        Debug.Log("The 'S' Key was not Pressed!");
        canRespond = false;
        yield return ResetGame();
    }

    IEnumerator ResetGame() {
        Debug.Log("Game is Performing a Reset");
        Simulating Game Reset Time.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(30);
        Debug.Log("Game has Restarted. End of Coroutine!");
    }
}
```

Comment: There are 60 seconds in a minute. Change your times based on that?

Comment: I'll go with Mars here: keep it simple and multiply by 60.

Answer (score 2):

```cs
float waitTimeSeconds = 0.0f;
float waitTimeMinutes = 1.0f;
int formatMinutesFlag = 1;    //this flag is 1 if you want to add minutes
yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTimeSeconds + formatMinutesFlag * waitTimeMinutes * 60f);
```

You can put this in a function if you really don't want to multiply by 60 everytime you want to use minutes instead of seconds.

Edit: Added the part where you multiply by 60. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Congrats, your wait for minutes converter waits for 1 second! `(0 + 1 * 1) == 1`

Comment: ^^ I'm sure you wanted to multiply by 60 somewhere?